# Setting a cell with #¡value! (error value) VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Can I set a cell with value: **#¡value!** (error value) using vba? if it posible, how can I do it?

Comment: Do you mean you want to put the #VALUE! error value in a cell, or just that text?

Comment: @Rory I'd like to put the error value if it posible.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ReturningErrors.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
Public Function MakeError(codee As Double) As Variant
    MakeError = CVErr(codee)
End Function
```

and to use:

[image]